# express app throwing error while displaying dynamic chart using flot in the jade client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, flot

While trying to display the realtime data using flot chart, I am getting the following error in the client code

```
  Uncaught Invalid dimensions for plot, width = 1584, height = 0
```

Cant figure out why the height = 0. I think something is wrong in my index.jade file. Seems its throwing error in the following statement in index.jade

```
var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ getInitData() ], options);
```

Here are my app.js, index.js, index.jade and style.css.

**App.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);

var httpServer = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpServer);   
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
socket.emit('welcome', {'salutation':'TMP36 Sensor output!'});      
});
```

**index.js file**

```
exports.index = function(req, res){  
res.render('index', { title: 'Temperature Monitor',
          domain: 'localhost'  });
};
```

**index.jade**

```
doctype 5
html
  head
    title= title
    script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js')       
script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/flot/jquery.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/flot/jquery.flot.js')      
script(type='text/javascript', src='./socket.io/socket.io.js')  
script
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    var socket = io.connect();
    var val = 10;
    var temp;
    var totalPoints = 300;
    var res = [];      
    function getInitData() {// zip the generated y values with the x values
      for (var i = 0; i < totalPoints; ++i){
        res.push([i, 0]);        
      }
      return res;        
    }      
    // Options for Flot plot        
    var options = {        
        series: { shadowSize: 0 }, // drawing is faster without shadows        
        yaxis: { min: 0, max: 50, color: "#bbbb00" },            
        xaxis: { show: false },   
    };  
    var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ getInitData() ], options);
    socket.on('welcome', function(data) {  
      val = data.salutation ;
      res.push([totalPoints, val]); // push on the end side
      res.shift(); // remove first value to maintain 300 points
      for (i=0;i<totalPoints;i++) { res[i][0] = i; }
      plot.setData([ res ]);
      plot.draw(); 
      $('#temperature').text("Current Temperature: :" + val );          
    });        
  });
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    h1= title
    p Welcome to #{title}
    #placeholder
    p graph here
    #temperature
    p temperature val
```

**Style.css**
    h1, h2, h3 { font-size: 22px; color: #464646; }

```
body {
  padding: 50px;
  font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: #00B7FF;
}
placeholder {
  width:600px;
  height:300px;
}
```

I have a equivalent html client of index.jade which works fine. I hit the above error while converting the html version of the client to jade.
The html version of the client is -

**index.html**

```
<!--!DOCTYPE html-->
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <title>Data Collector</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js'></script>      
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../3rdParty/flot/jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../3rdParty/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>        
    <script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>     
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var socket = io.connect();
        var val = 10;
        var temp ;          
        var totalPoints = 300;
        var res = [];
        function getInitData() {
            // zip the generated y values with the x values
            for (var i = 0; i < totalPoints; ++i){
                res.push([i, 0]);
            }
            return res;
        }
        // Options for Flot plot
        var options = {
            series: { shadowSize: 0 }, // drawing is faster without shadows
            yaxis: { min: 0, max: 50, color: "#bbbb00" },
            xaxis: { show: false },             
        };
        var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ getInitData() ], options);           
        socket.on('welcome', function(data) {
            // Convert value to integer
            //val = ((parseInt(data.salutation) / 1023)*100)*10;
            val = data.salutation ;
            // Push new value to Flot Plot
            res.push([totalPoints, val]); // push on the end side
            res.shift(); // remove first value to maintain 300 points
            // reinitialize the x axis data points to 0 to 299.
            for (i=0;i<totalPoints;i++) { res[i][0] = i; }
            // Redraw the plot
            plot.setData([ res ]);
            plot.draw();                
            $('#temperature').text("Current Temperature: :" + val );                                
        });
    });
    </script>       
</head>
<body>      
    <h1>Temperature Monitor</h1>        
    <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
    <div id='temperature'><p>Temperature</p></div>      
</body>
```

This is the output of the html client[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flot needs to be able to read the width & height of the placeholder div.  Your Jade output produces a placeholder with no set height, and no derived height from any parent or child elements.  Its height is therefore zero, which prevents Flot from using it.

Your HTML example works because you have set the width & height using an inline style.

Comment: DNS, I forgot to mention that I have a stylesheet for the jade client. Added the style.css content in the original thread. The sytle.css specifies the width and height for the flot chart. However I have noticed when the jade file gets compiled to html it doesn't have the height and width. May be thats the problem ?? So does it mean I have to set the width and height in the index.jade using an inline style??

Comment: Thanks DNS. I was able to fix it by replacing the line '#placeholder' with '#placeholder(style='width: 600px; height: 300px;');'. Any idea why the #placeholder was not able to get width and height when I had specified the link to stylesheet ?

Comment: It's because your 'placeholder' CSS rule is missing a leading hash mark.  Your rule applies to <placeholder> elements; to get it to work with an element whose *id* has that value you should instead use '#placeholder'.